# Trouble with Alpine php-fpm configuration (xdebug+netbeans, sendmail+mailhog)

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, xdebug

I'm trying to setup development environment for one PHP application but **I can't solve these two things**:

- **sending emails** (I would like use MailHog which is running but it seems that I haven't correct PHP configuration)
- **xdebug** (is installed and log is working **but I can not connect it from NetBeans IDE**)

Here is my configuration:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    # MySQL
    database:
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_USER: testuser
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: testpass
            MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb
        image: mariadb
        restart: always
    volumes:
        - "./docker/mariadb/data:/var/lib/mysql"
        - "./docker/mariadb/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    # PHP
    php-fpm:
        build:
            context: ./docker/php-fpm
        environment:
            ENV_MODE: development
        ENV_BRANCH: test
    volumes:
        - "./:/var/www/app"
    # NGINX
    webserver:
        build:
            context: ./docker/nginx
        depends_on:
            - php-fpm
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb
            MYSQL_USER: testuser
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: testpass
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        links:
            - database:mysql
            - mailhog
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - "./:/var/www/inpage"
            - "./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
            - "./docker/nginx/inpage.inc.conf:/etc/nginx/inpage.inc.conf"
            - "./docker/nginx/inpage-site.inc.conf:/etc/nginx/app-site.inc.conf"
            - "./docker/nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available"
            - "./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
    # Adminer
    adminer:
        depends_on:
            - database
        environment:
            ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: database
        image: adminer
        ports:
            - 8181:8080
        restart: always
    # MailHog
    mailhog:
        image: mailhog/mailhog
        command: -smtp-bind-addr 127.0.0.1:1025
        user: root
        expose:
            - 1025
            - 8025
        ports:
            - 1025:1025
            - 8025:8025
```

**docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile:**

```
# Customized Dockerfile from https://github.com/kporras07/docker-php.
FROM php:7.0-fpm-alpine

# Environment settings
ENV XDEBUG_VERSION 2.3.3
ENV PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT 256M
ENV PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME 120
ENV PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE 100M
ENV PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE 100M
ENV PHP_INI_DIR /usr/local/etc/php

# Configure, build & install PHP
RUN docker-php-source extract \
    && apk --no-cache --update add \
        libxml2-dev \
        libpng \
        libpng-dev \
        libjpeg-turbo \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev \
        freetype-dev \
        freetype \
        libcurl \
        curl-dev \
        curl \
        icu-dev \
        g++ \
        autoconf \
        make \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libmcrypt \
        libintl \
        openssl-dev \
        re2c \
        recode-dev \
        sqlite-dev \
        enchant-dev \
        krb5-dev \
        pcre-dev \
        imagemagick-dev \
        imagemagick \
        libtool \
        bzip2-dev \
        freetds-dev \
        freetype-dev \
        gmp-dev \
        imap-dev \
        readline-dev \
        recode-dev \
        zip \
        libzip \
        libzip-dev \
        libxslt \
        libxslt-dev \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && docker-php-ext-configure bcmath \
    && docker-php-ext-configure bz2 \
    && docker-php-ext-configure json \
    && docker-php-ext-configure session \
    && docker-php-ext-configure ctype \
    && docker-php-ext-configure curl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure tokenizer \
    && docker-php-ext-configure simplexml \
    && docker-php-ext-configure dom \
    && docker-php-ext-configure mbstring \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-configure xml \
    && docker-php-ext-configure opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_sqlite \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gettext \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gmp \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl --enable-intl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure phar \
    && docker-php-ext-configure soap \
    && docker-php-ext-configure sockets \
    && docker-php-ext-configure xml \
    && docker-php-ext-configure xsl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
        --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
        --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && NPROC=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || 1) \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j${NPROC} gd \
    && docker-php-source delete

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath \
    bz2 \
    json \
    session \
    ctype \
    curl \
    tokenizer \
    simplexml \
    dom \
    mbstring \
    zip \
    iconv \
    xml \
    opcache \
    pdo \
    pdo_mysql \
    gettext \
    gmp \
    intl \
    mcrypt \
    phar \
    soap \
    sockets \
    xml \
    xsl

RUN apk update \
    && apk add ca-certificates wget \
    && update-ca-certificates

# Blackfire.io
RUN version=$(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.PHP_MINOR_VERSION;") \
    && curl -A "Docker" -o /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz -D - -L -s https://blackfire.io/api/v1/releases/probe/php/alpine/amd64/$version \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/blackfire \
    && tar zxpf /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz -C /tmp/blackfire \
    && mv /tmp/blackfire/blackfire-*.so $(php -r "echo ini_get('extension_dir');")/blackfire.so \
    && printf "extension=blackfire.so\nblackfire.agent_socket=tcp://blackfire:8707\n" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/blackfire.ini \
    && rm -rf /tmp/blackfire /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz

# Xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
COPY ./xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

## mhsendmail for MailHog (https://github.com/mailhog/mhsendmail)
RUN apk update && apk add \
    go \
    git
RUN mkdir /root/go
ENV GOPATH=/root/go
ENV PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
RUN go get github.com/mailhog/mhsendmail
RUN cp /root/go/bin/mhsendmail /usr/bin/mhsendmail
COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php.ini

# Fix iconv lib (https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/240#issuecomment-305038173)
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing gnu-libiconv
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so php

# Cleanup
RUN rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && rm -rf tmp/*

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

**docker/php-fpm/xdebug.ini:**

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.coverage_enable=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
;xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
;xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

**docker/php-fpm/php.ini:**

```
memory_limit = ${PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT}
max_execution_time = ${PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME}
post_max_size=${PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE}
upload_max_filesize=${PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE}
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/mhsendmail -S mailhog:1025 -t
```

Comment: Currently I tried to connect directly to php-fpm container with `docker exec -it php-fpm_1 bash` and tried to send email directly using mhsendmail from the command line, but I got `2018/12/06 08:33:19 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1025: getsockopt: connection refused` ... Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the mailhog 'connection refused' part of this question on the [mailhog github issues](https://github.com/mailhog/mhsendmail/issues/25) pages. You need to replace the `sendmail_path` statement in your
docker/php-fpm/php.ini with something like this (the -S option isn't supported, and the position of the quote marks is important):

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/mhsendmail --smtp-addr=mailhog:1025"
```

Also I found that I didn't need to use the `command`, `user` or `expose` parts of the mailhog service section in the docker-compose file.